# Magento undefined constant

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento-1.4

hi have a problems with magento as it shows me this error when i click sunglasses menu:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id'  in /var/www/app/design/frontend/glassesonline/default/template/mana/filters/items/list.phtml on line 159
```

This is code at line 159

```
<input id="category" type="hidden"  value="<?php $arr = $this->getRequest()->getParams(id,false); echo $arr['id']; ?>">
```

This drive me crazy, please let me know where am i wrong, i will provide more info if needed.Thanks

Comment: Use if(isset($arr['id'])) before echo $arr['id'] on that line.

Answer (score 2):

it should be:

```
<input id="category" type="hidden"  value="<?php $arr = $this->getRequest()->getParams('id',false); echo $arr['id']; ?>">
                                                                                        ^^^
```

you are missing quotes here and PHP is thinking you are trying to use a defined varuiable which you do not have. Always use quotes for strings.